# Order rows using columns from less number of null to no nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle19c, sql-null

Hello guys i have the next problem:

Having this query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_prices MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2206 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;


CREATE TABLE PRICES_INFO ( 
     ID NUMBER(19,0) DEFAULT SEQ_prices.nextval  NOT NULL
    ,QUARTER VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T1 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T2 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T3 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T4 NUMBER(19,0)
    ,COD_T5 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T6 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T7 NUMBER(19,0)
    ,COD_T8 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,COD_T9 VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
    ,PREC_T1    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T2    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T3    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T4    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T5    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T6    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T7    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T8    NUMBER(19,6)
    ,PREC_T9    NUMBER(19,6)
);
```

and also those inserts:

```
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'PEUY', null, null, 856, null, null, 711, 'TZRS', null, 98.1, null, 12.69, 83.09, 77.32, null, null, 13.3, null);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'XWIK', 'EZYI', 'GJJL', null, null, 'KQMH', 771, 'FENL', 'CUPQ', null, 75.19, 61.56, null, 72.09, null, null, 54.32, 66.32);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', null, 'QUCJ', 'PZEG', 511, 'KWVY', 'LUPZ', 725, null, null, null, 89.12, null, 32.15, 20.43, null, null, 48.21, 58.19);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', null, null, 'HDWM', null, null, null, 865, null, 'ZTQA', 98.16, null, null, 88.48, null, 12.68, null, null, 23.04);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'TVDB', null, 'LCVE', null, 'OEDD', null, null, 'JQTL', 'CWFH', null, 95.98, null, 56.02, 26.02, null, null, null, 53.9);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'QODQ', 'YCGT', null, 289, null, 'GSHJ', null, null, 'PXGZ', 44.8, 58.98, 83.21, 22.77, null, null, 98.47, 66.39, 41.09);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'UNJU', null, 'DQNN', null, 'CQSL', null, null, null, null, 31.43, null, 81.36, null, 37.27, 58.15, null, null, null);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', null, 'XDMW', 'QLVX', 995, 'UGWE', null, 593, 'QPJT', null, null, 26, 32.89, 60.81, null, null, null, null, null);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', 'ELCV', 'PGPF', null, 892, 'VNXH', null, 435, null, null, null, null, null, 48.17, 70.64, 95.88, 71.31, null, null);
insert into prices_info (quarter, cod_t1, cod_t2, cod_t3, cod_t4, cod_t5, cod_t6, cod_t7, cod_t8, cod_t9, prec_t1, prec_t2, prec_t3, prec_t4, prec_t5, prec_t6, prec_t7, prec_t8, prec_t9) values ('Q1', null, 'BKOD', 'HYBX', 839, 'KWGD', null, 229, null, 'NPRL', 65.32, null, 94.17, 20.97, 36.97, 46.27, null, null, 18.91);
```

i need to order those rows in order to see this:

[image]

I was thinking use cursor to see the result, but i need the to know the name of the header (because if you see the image on every interaction the header change) and also the information that is contained on that header and the rest of the information (all columns PREC_XXX)

And to say the true, i don't have a idea how to start, can somebody help me with this?

Best regards

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store values across columsn!

Comment: Hmm, what about `order by cod_t1 nulls last, cod_t2 nulls last, ...`?

Answer (score 0):

This is rather painful. Basically one method uses a giant addition of `case` expressions, like:

```
order by 
    (case when cod_t1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case when cod_t2 is null then 1 else 0 end)
    + (case when cod_t3 is null then 1 else 0 end)
    + ...
```

It would be much simpler to fix your data model to store the codes as *rows* rather than columns. Then, you could use aggregation:

```
select id, quarter
from mytable
group by id, quarter
order by count(cod) desc
```

Comment: but this is not the case, the table is prepared on that form , and my job is show rows (10 interaction) with picture show

Comment: @Julio: then use the `order by` suggested at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join and aggregate.  This should work:

```
select id, quarter,
       max(case when seqnum_cod = 1 then cod end) as cod_1,
       max(case when seqnum_cod = 2 then cod end) as cod_2,
       . . .,
       max(case when seqnum_prec = 1 then cod end) as prec_1,
       max(case when seqnum_prec = 2 then cod end) as prec_2,
       . . .,
from (select pi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pi.id
                                order by (case when cod is not null then ord end) nulls last
                               ) as seqnum_cod,
             row_number() over (partition by pi.id
                                order by (case when prec is not null then ord end) nulls last
                               ) as seqnum_prec,
      from prices_info pi cross join lateral
           (select pi.cod_t1 as cod, prec_t1 as prec, 1 as ord from dual union all
            select pi.cod_t2 as cod, prec_t2, 2 as ord from dual union all
            . . . 
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, quarter;
```